# Butterknife throws java.lang.IllegalStateException because a view (not existing now) is not found

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

I'm using Butterknife 8.8.1. Unfortunately android studio throws an IllegalStateException because a view with respective id (which I renamed through refactor menu) cannot be found!

```
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aristo.nvn.aristo/com.aristo.nvn.aristo.EditorActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'add_color_rv' with ID 2131361821 for field 'mColorsRecyclerView' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
```

I renamed both add_color_rv id and variable mColorsRecyclerView to use following

```
@BindView(R.id.text_colors_rv) RecyclerView mTextColorsRecyclerView;
```

Then I bind in onCreateView()

```
Butterknife.bind(this);
```

Dependencies-

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Developing my first app! Help. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention in ques. but I did.

Comment: also check in you layout that recyclerview has id `text_colors_rv`

Comment: I have already checked for all basic errors

Comment: I'm not too noob. Please consider looking at the exception again. The id & variable is not even existing in my code. That's what bugging me.

Comment: Try to `Clean-ReBuild` Your project

Comment: Did that already. Do you think it may be a bug in butterknife?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you prevent the crash:

```
@Nullable // use annotation from support library.
@BindView(R.id.text_colors_rv) 
RecyclerView mTextColorsRecyclerView;
```

> **Note:** *Due to **R** file changes, **ButterKnife** loses it's reference to view id and thus crashes. Consider rebuilding project and then
>   deploy apk.*

Comment: Please read the exception thrown again please. It nowhere mentioned something about this view.

Comment: But I'll try. Thanks